# Can't access Eureka form object from outside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, forms, viewdidload, eureka-forms

I'm trying to create a Eureka form for editing / creating a task object. Now, I segue to the view and pass on a Task object as class variable, but for some reason it is not accessible from **viewDidLoad** where I'm creating the form. This means I can't assign values to the form. When I create a **didSet** method for the Task class variable, it gets called eventually, but then the form object is an empty object, as when I look **form.values()** there is nothing. But in **viewDidLoad** it works. Any suggestions what am I missing?

```
var task: Task? { didSet { print("didSet values:", form.values(), "didSet task name", task?.name) } }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    form +++ Section()
        <<< TextRow("name"){
            $0.title = "Name"
        }

    print("viewDidLoad values:", form.values(), "viewDidLoad task name", task?.name)
}
```

and output

```
viewDidLoad values: ["name": nil, "deadline": Optional(2017-06-08 19:02:39 +0000)] viewDidLoad task name nil
didSet values: [:] didSet task name Optional("ascasc")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after debugging I found that there were two different instances of the Eureka form view. So after digging I found that I did two segues doing the same thing. One segue from storyboard tableView cell to the form, and other from code by **didSelectRowAt** and **performSegue**. Interesting that I didn't find this when I debugged the **prepare(for segue:)** from the controller which called the form view, it should have printed the output twice, but I saw only one, so I was always thinking I was creating only one segue.